# Spring Batch multiple steps per item read

Tags: spring, spring-batch

My question is: In spring batch, what is the best way to read an item of data and process it  multiple times, with potential output from each processor.

Each atomic input data object will have an ID and two lists of date/time objects.

Each processor will look at the list of date times to determine if an action record should be generated.  This action record will be written to the database.

Am I trying to solve this problem the right way?

I want to read once, then process1/write, process2/write, process3/write.  The process/write actions can be run asynchronously.

Example processes:
1) missing date-time object (must be in pairs)
2) no date-time objects
3) list1 item1 date-time object is before list2 item1 date-time object

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just an idea...Is it ok if you have a [chain](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#chainingItemProcessors) processor and depending the case you will trigger a batch stream(writer)? Example: item1 -> processor1(no action record) -> processor2(write to stream/action record) -> processor3(write to stream/action record) -> actualWriter(nothing really, everything is done in processing). The same logic can be applied with chain writers too.

Comment: I am using JPA to write the results of the processors.  Are you saying to persist the record in the processor?  I guess that would work, at which point I should probably look at a Tasklet instead of a Step.  Interesting idea that I'll have to play with.  Right now I am looking into a step that writes the data to the ExecutionContext, and then using Partitioning I will do a split flow and have the readers pull the data from the ExecutionContext.